# When I define the Angular controller in a separate file, it loads controller file before the Module file

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have done following things:

1. Created a module with the correct convention: `var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);` As you can see I was mindful to put the [] as  second param
2. I created some controllers inside the same file and it works absolutely fine with following convention: `var myApp = angular.module('myApp').Controller(...)`

Now, while cleaning up my code I decided to move these controllers to separate file and my module started failing with following error:

> aught Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'maintenance.portability.module'
>   is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to
>   load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the
>   dependencies as the second argument.(…)

It sounds like it is loading the separate controller file before the module file. How do I make sure that Module file is loaded before my browser tries to load the separate Controller file?

Comment: Did you remember to include your new file in your index.html scripts? Or, if you are using any minify technique, is this file included in the pattern of files to minify?

Comment: I think the problem is that it is trying to load the separate Controller file before it loads the Module fine and it is really not able to find the original module definition. I updated the question is with my thoughts. However, to answer your question, we are not using any minification technique

Comment: This also might be the case, though it depends more on the order in which you are importing your scripts. You must import your module's file first.

Answer (score 0):

There might be a more correct way to do this with modules but I just use gulp to concatenate everything into the same file. Here is my gulpfile:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
var babel = require('gulp-babel');

gulp.task('default', ['scripts', 'scripts:watch']);

gulp.task('scripts', function() {
  return gulp.src('path/to/javascript/files/**/*.js')
    .pipe(babel({
      presets: ['es2015']
    }))
    .pipe(concat('app.min.js'))
    .pipe(uglify({
      mangle: false
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/js'));
});

gulp.task('scripts:watch', function () {
  gulp.watch('path/to/javascript/files/**/*.js', ['scripts']);
});
```

This takes all of your JavaScript files, transpiles them to es5, concatenates them all together, minimizes them, then puts them in your public JavaScript folder for deployment. The watch task does this every time you save one of the javascript as long as you have gulp running. Make sure you have mangle set to false, angular is particular with variable names in my experience.